# How to iterate through a directory of text files, pull specific lines, and write to a csv

Tags: python, csv, text, directory

Extremely novice coder here so please excuse my syntax errors.

My goal with this script is to:

- Iterate through a directory of text files (text files are all the same format)
- Pull values from specific lines in the text file (a subset of characters in the line)
- Write these values to a common csv

My code is below.  I'm having trouble getting this code to execute properly.  I've tried to break it down into it's individual components to test, but I'm not having much luck.  I'm having particular trouble trying to handle the nested indices to look at for ex/ line 41 and characters 3:6 of that line.

```
def main():
    get_project_location()
    get_file_variables()

    for filename in path_txt_files:
        with open(filename, 'r') as file:
            for line in file.readlines():
                with open('csv_output.csv', 'w+') as csv_output:
                    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_output, delimiter=',')
                    csv_writer.writerow(line[41[3:6]])
                    csv_writer.writerow(line[121[3:6]])
                    close(filename)

def get_project_location():
    return os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

def get_file_variables():
    path_txt_files = os.path.join(
        get_project_location(),
        'txt_file_directory')
```

Comment: Something seems off with your indexing syntax. Did you mean line[41][3:6] instead of line[41[3:6]]? In your code snippet, you are trying to slice an object called 41 which is not correct

Comment: and likewise with `121[3:6]`

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to slice characters 3:6 out of line 41 so your is probably right, thanks!

Comment: You seem to expect that calling `get_file_variables()` will allow you to directly access its local variable `path_txt_files`, but that's not how it works.  You have to _return_ that value from the function, and then _capture_ the value in the calling context.  Also, `path_txt_files` is just a string containing a directory name; it's not a list of actual filenames in that directory as you seem to expect.  Use `os.listdir('/some/directory')` for that.